# hover box floating down while hovering

Tags: html, css, hover

i was working o this [**site**](http://beta.jointviews.com/contact-us/) , the password is **joint123** , ase you can see a map with icons on the right side,when we hover the icon it shows the corresponding adders .its showing ,but when we hover towards the lower icons the footer div is also moving down.what can be the problem? please help!!

here is my html and css

```css
 .cont-map {
   background: url('http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/map1.png')no-repeat;
   width: 590px;
   float: right;
 }
 .box1,
 .box2,
 .box3,
 .box4,
 .box5,
 .box6 {
   display: none;
 }
 .img-1:hover .box1,
 .img-2:hover .box2,
 .img-3:hover .box3,
 .img-4:hover .box4,
 .img-5:hover .box5,
 .img-6:hover .box6 {
   display: block;
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid;
   padding: 10px;
   /*width:250px;*/
   float: right;
 }
 .img-1,
 .img-2,
 .img-3,
 .img-4,
 .img-5,
 .img-6 {
   width: 300px;
 }
 .box1 p img,
 .box2 p img,
 .box3 p img,
 .box4 p img,
 .box5 p img,
 .box6 p img {
   width: 50px;
 }
 .p-1 {
   height: 50px;
   padding-top: 130px;
   margin-left: 39.5%;
   font-size: 4px;
   line-height: 1px;
 }
 .p-2 {
   height: 50px;
   padding-top: 155px;
   margin-left: 29.5%;
 }
 .p-3 {
   height: 50px;
   padding-top: 33px;
   margin-left: 39.5%;
 }
 .p-4 {
   height: 10px;
   margin-left: 36.5%;
 }
 .p-5 {
   margin-left: 36.5%;
 }
 .p-6 {
   margin-top: -49px;
   margin-left: 38.2%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="cont-map">
  <div class="p-1">
    <div class="img-1">
      <img style="float:left;" src="http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mapicon.png">
      <div class="box1">
        <p>
          <img style="float:left;" src="http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/edsys-logo1.png">Regional Office: Noida B-81, Sector -65 Noida, UP – 201301 India
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-2">
    <div class="img-2">
      <img style="float:left;" src="http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mapicon.png">
      <div class="box2">
        <p>
          <img style="float:left;" src="http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/edsys-logo1.png">Corporate Office: Pune 315 Aurora Tower Camp Pune-411001, Maharashtra India
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-3">
    <div class="img-3">
      <img src="http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mapicon.png">
      <div class="box3">
        <p>
          <img style="float:left;" src="http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-    content/uploads/2015/01/edsys-logo1.png">Marketing Office: Bangalore Caravel Tower #13/15/2, S.T. Bd Area Koramangala, Bengaluru India
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-4">
    <div class="img-4">
      <img src="http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mapicon.png">
      <div class="box4">
        <p>
          <img style="float:left;" src="http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/edsys-logo1.png">Associate office: Calicut M.S.S Complex Cherooty Road Kozhikode, India</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-5">
    <div class="img-5">
      <img src="http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mapicon.png">
      <div class="box5">
        <p>
          <img style="float:left;" src="http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/edsys-logo1.png">Regional Office: Cochin Velayudhan vaidyans`s building, Padma Jn., M.G. Road Kochi – 682 035 India
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-6">
    <div class="img-6">
      <img src="http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mapicon.png">
      <div class="box6">
        <p>
          <img style="float:left;" src="http://beta.jointviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/edsys-logo1.png">Regional Office: Trivandrum Edsys Towers, Kamaleswaram Thiruvananthapurum -695009 India
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boxes are still in the flow, so they are pushing the footer down when they are visible. Try:

```
.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

This will take them out of the flow.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the boxes position absolute, for it to float above the page and not take-up space.

style.css, line: 2161

```
 .box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6 {
   display: none;
   position: absolute; /* add this line */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
.img-1,.img-2,.img-3,.img-4,.img-5,.img-6 {width: 300px;position:relative;}
.box1,.box2,.box3,.box4,.box5,.box6 {display: none;position:absolute;top:30px;left:0;}
```